# Split an array of items into several arrays, given a condition

Tags: javascript

The question is very simple : I have an array of items, that all have a date. According to the date, I would like to split this array into several arrays.

In my case, I would like to split the array into 3 arrays : one that contains result of the last 24h, the other 48h, then the last one on the week.

Here is a minimal reproduction of the case, with the final solution.

```js
const now = Date.now();
const day = 1000 * 3600 * 24;

const todayTime = now - day;
const yesterdayTime = now - day * 2;
const weekTime = now - day * 7;

const arr = [
  { id: 1, date: todayTime + 100 },
  { id: 2, date: yesterdayTime + 100 },
  { id: 3, date: weekTime + 100 },
];

const today = arr.filter(item => item.date - todayTime > 0);
const yesterday = arr.filter(item => item.date - yesterdayTime > 0 && item.date - todayTime < 0);
const week = arr.filter(item => item.date - weekTime > 0 && item.date - yesterdayTime < 0);

console.log(today, yesterday, week);
```

Is there a way to make it more concise ? I'm talking about code length : I would like to reduce it to the maximum, especially the definition of the 3 arrays. I tried with reduce, but the syntax is pretty ugly.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Sounds like this question belongs to the codereview site instead.

Comment: Instead of subtracting, you could simplify the conditions to `item.date > todayTime` and `item.date > yesterdayTime && item.date < todayTime` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not shorter, but I would go for a more generic function which groups data into chunks based on a given property ("date" in your case) and some boundary values (you have 3), provided in ascending order. Then that function would return one more value, since 3 boundaries split an infinite range into 4 ranges, ...etc.

So this is what that function would look like:

```js
function groupInRanges(data, prop, boundaries) {
    // NB: boundaries must be sorted ascending.
    return data.reduce((acc, item) => {
        let index = boundaries.findIndex(boundary => item[prop] < boundary);
        if (index < 0) index = boundaries.length;
        acc[index].push(item);
        return acc;
    }, [[], ...boundaries.map(() => [])]);
}

// Demo
const now = Date.now();
const day = 1000 * 3600 * 24;

const arr = [
  { id: 1, date: now - day + 100 },
  { id: 2, date: now - 2*day + 100 },
  { id: 3, date: now - 5*day },
];

// We are not interested in the first value (data older than 1 week):
const [, week, yesterday, today] = groupInRanges(arr, "date", [now-day*7, now-day*2, now-day]);

console.log(today, yesterday, week);
```

Note that if your data could possibly have *future* dates, you would need one extra boundary set to `now`.

#### More specific solution

This assumes that there is no data older than a week or future. Use a ternary operator to determine in which array a data item should be pushed:

```js
const now = Date.now();
const day = 1000 * 3600 * 24;

const todayTime = now - day;
const yesterdayTime = now - day * 2;
const weekTime = now - day * 7;

const arr = [
  { id: 1, date: todayTime + 100 },
  { id: 2, date: yesterdayTime + 100 },
  { id: 3, date: weekTime + 100 },
];

const [today, yesterday, week] = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item.date > todayTime ? 0 : item.date > yesterdayTime ? 1 : 2].push(item);
    return acc;
}, [[], [], []]);

console.log(today, yesterday, week);
```

A tiny bit shorter, but less readable, with the comma operator and expression arrow-function syntax:

```
const [today, yesterday, week] = arr.reduce((acc, item) =>
    (acc[item.date > todayTime ? 0 : item.date > yesterdayTime ? 1 : 2].push(item), acc)
, [[], [], []]);
```

Comment: I have a very specific use case, the data gets deleted if it goes after a week. I really don't need genericity (if that word exists), that's why I thought some `split` variation would exist.

Comment: Not sure how you would imagine a `split` variation? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well I don't, that's kind of the point of my question ! I thought some function would exist (or would be easy to code with array operators) that would split an array into several ones, given a condition.

Comment: OK, I added a non-generic solution, with some assumptions. I don't think it can get much shorter than that.

Comment: That was my original solution with `reduce` ... Guess that if you can't make it shorter, I'll settle for that. Thank you for your help anyway !

Comment: Wait, "more generic"? You just said "I really don't need genericity". I am lost ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could move the function into an array and get the index for later pushing the item.

```js
const
    update = (array, index, value) => {
        if (index !== -1) (array[index] = array[index] || []).push(value);
        return array;
    },
    now = Date.now(),
    day = 1000 * 3600 * 24,
    todayTime = now - day,
    yesterdayTime = now - day * 2,
    weekTime = now - day * 7,
    arr = [{ id: 1, date: todayTime + 100 }, { id: 2, date: yesterdayTime + 100 }, { id: 3, date: weekTime + 100 }],
    fns = [
       date => date - todayTime > 0,
       date => date - yesterdayTime > 0 && date - todayTime < 0,
       date => date - weekTime > 0 && date - yesterdayTime < 0,
    ],
    result = arr.reduce(
        (r, item) => update(r, fns.findIndex(f => f(item.date)), item),
        fns.map(_ => [])
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not that shorter ... I thought some `split` variation with a callback would exist, but your solution doesn't seem to shorten the code (and uses a complicated syntax, making it a bit harder to read)

Answer (score 0):

You want to make following part more concise right?

```
const today = arr.filter(item => item.date - todayTime > 0);
const yesterday = arr.filter(item => item.date - yesterdayTime > 0 && item.date - todayTime < 0);
const week = arr.filter(item => item.date - weekTime > 0 && item.date - yesterdayTime < 0);
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
const [today, yesterday, week] = arr.reduce((result, item) => (index = item.date - todayTime > 0 ? 0 : item.date - yesterdayTime > 0 && item.date - todayTime < 0 ? 1 : 2, result[index].push(item), result), [[], [], []])
```

Final code is:

```js
const now = Date.now();
const day = 1000 * 3600 * 24;

const todayTime = now - day;
const yesterdayTime = now - day * 2;
const weekTime = now - day * 7;

const arr = [
  { id: 1, date: todayTime + 100 },
  { id: 2, date: yesterdayTime + 100 },
  { id: 3, date: weekTime + 100 },
];

// revised
const [today, yesterday, week] = arr.reduce((result, item) => (index = item.date - todayTime > 0 ? 0 : item.date - yesterdayTime > 0 && item.date - todayTime < 0 ? 1 : 2, result[index].push(item), result), [[], [], []])

console.log(today, yesterday, week)
```

Comment: Using reduce was my original solution, and it doesn't make it more concise, just harder to read ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like most of the other answers.

This simply works by comparing the dates, removing the `item` from the array if it matches a certain criteria. In the example below I duplicate the array leaving the old `arr` intact. However you can simply ignore this if you don't care about `arr` mutating, or if you'd like to see what items didn't match any criteria (since they are left behind).

The reason I need a `reverseEach` function is obvious. If I start deleting items from an array that I'm currently iterating over the elements start to shift. When iterating from back to front this doesn't matter since I've already handled those items.

In the example below, order matters. When you put `t1w` (time 1 week) as first element in the array all the elements of `arr` will match the criteria and will be present in that group. Make sure you provide the criteria incremental (or decremental depending on the context).

```js
// define some helpers
Array.prototype.deleteAt = function (index) { return this.splice(index, 1)[0]; };
Array.prototype.dup = function () { return this.slice(0); };
Array.prototype.reverseEach = function (callback, thisArg) {
  if (thisArg !== undefined) callback = callback.bind(thisArg);
  for (let index = this.length - 1; index >= 0; index -= 1) {
    callback(this[index], index, this);
  }
};

// initialisation
const now = Date.now();
const day = 1000 * 3600 * 24;

const t1d = now - day;
const t2d = now - day * 2;
const t1w = now - day * 7;

const arr = [
  { id: 1, date: t1d + 100 },
  { id: 2, date: t2d + 100 },
  { id: 3, date: t1w + 100 },
];

// actual answer
const groups = [t1d, t2d, t1w].map(function (limit) {
  const group = [];
  this.reverseEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.date > limit) group.unshift(this.deleteAt(index));
  });
  return group;
}, arr.dup());

console.log(groups);
```